# How to improve my gamma GLM's very low deviance?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

I have a query about the results of my GLM, especially the deviance. I ran the GLM as follows on data relating to blood vessel thickness (measure) and possible explanatory variables. As a note, We were asked to keep packyear in regardless of p value.

```
glm3 <- glm(measure ~ AGE + BMI + packyear, family = Gamma(link = log), data = Intima2)
summary(glm3)
```

```
Call:
glm(formula = measure ~ AGE + BMI + packyear, family = Gamma(link = log), 
    data = Intima2)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.30117  -0.08328  -0.01571   0.06458   0.39219  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.1338622  0.0807785 -14.037  < 2e-16 ***
AGE          0.0073254  0.0011212   6.534 2.29e-09 ***
BMI         86.0179269 31.5763694   2.724  0.00754 ** 
packyear     0.0003447  0.0013512   0.255  0.79914    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.01603842)

    Null deviance: 2.6334  on 109  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.6348  on 106  degrees of freedom
AIC: -282.74

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Everything looks good to me except the deviance, but I'm not sure what the exceptionally low deviances mean or how to fix them, or even if I need to?

Thanks very much for any help!
Cheers,
D

Comment: Why do you think that a low deviance is worrisome? Low deviance usually indicates a good model fit (it's the difference between the log-likelihood of the saturated model and the model in question).

Comment: In general, the deviance (and other information criteria) cannot be interpreted as is, but only in comparison to another model's deviance.

Comment: @BalaGizeh While that is true, I get the feeling that the OP has mixed up wanting to minimize deviance with wanting to maximize, getting into a position of having the tell the boss, "I'm sorry, boss, but the model performance is awful. Look how low the deviance is!" No no no...we like small deviance, just like we like small MSE in linear regression.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments - I was mainly going off notes that indicated that the deviance should ideally be close to the DF and was worried that the low deviances was an indication that the model was not a good fit like you said!  Glad to hear that small deviance is hopefully an indication of a good model fit or as a comparison to other models.